# gmaps Address Component Types get country name

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

iam trying to get the country name using the Address Component Types available from gmaps V3.

i dont know how i can get it the right way.. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingAddressTypes

iam trying to alert the country name liks here :

```
alert(results[1].address_component[country]);
```

and here`s the code.. any help is really appreciated..thanks

```
function codeLatLng() { 
    var input = document.getElementById("latlng").value; 
    var latlngStr = input.split(",",2); 
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]); 
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]); 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); 
    if (geocoder) { 
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
          if (results[1]) { 
          alert(results[1].address_component[country]); 
          } else { 
            alert("No results found"); 
          } 
        } else { 
          alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status); 
        } 
      }); 
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

For one thing, address_components should be plural. The Google documentation is misleading on that due to a typo.

The address_components array has an item for each component of the address. The types array within each item tells you all of the types that apply to each address component (eg: country, locality, etc.) - So what you really want to do is find the address_components array item that has "country" as one of its types, and then take either the short_name or long_name for that array item.

Also, you may not always have a value for results[1]. That would assume there are at least 2 search results returned. results[0] would be the first one.

here's an example:

```
var country;

for (i=0;i<results[0].address_components.length;i++){
    for (j=0;j<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;j++){
       if(results[0].address_components[i].types[j]=="country")
          country = results[0].address_components[i].long_name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert(results[1].address_component['country']);` // country is a string

Answer (score -1):

According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), the results are always returned in the order of most specific to least specific:

> Generally, addresses are returned from most specific to least specific; the more exact address is the most prominent result, as it is in this case. Note that we return different types of addresses, from the most specific street address to less specific political entities such as neighborhoods, cities, counties, states, etc. If you wish to match a more general address, you may wish to inspect the `"types"` field of the returned `Placemark`s.

Given this fact we don't even have to loop through the results. Just pick the ones at the end:

```
alert(results.slice(-1)[0].address_components.slice(-1)[0].long_name);
```

If it turns out that "results" or "address_components" can be missing or length 0 some simple error checking could be added.

Comment: @Christoffer: What do you mean? An entry that is just a postal code alone with no other info?

Comment: No what I mean is that you assume that country is always the last address component right? But it isn't. You can trust the position, so you have to iterate through them

Comment: @Christoffer: If you can trust the position then why must you iterate through them? `\-:`

Comment: Sorry that should say can't trust the position